# GLUT exit redefinition error

Tags: opengl, glut

In my simple OpenGL program I get the following error about exit redefinition:

```
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\stdlib.h(406) : error C2381: 'exit' : redefinition; __declspec(noreturn) differs
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\platformsdk\include\gl\glut.h(146) : see declaration of 'exit'
```

I'm using Nate Robins' [GLUT for Win32](http://www.xmission.com/~nate/glut.html) and get this error with Visual Studio 2005 or Visual C++ 2005 (Express Edition). What is the cause of this error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

**Cause:**

The **stdlib.h** which ships with the recent versions of Visual Studio has a different (and conflicting) definition of the **exit()** function. It clashes with the definition in **glut.h**.

**Solution:**

Override the definition in glut.h with that in stdlib.h. Place the stdlib.h line above the glut.h line in your code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
```

Answer (score 21):

or this...
To fix the error, right click on the project name in the Solution Explorer tab and select Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor definitions and append GLUT_BUILDING_LIB to the existing definitions, seperated by semicolons.

Comment: Thanks! including stdlib.h above your glut.h didn't work for me.  This solution did!