# Why is exit(0) giving me errors?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, opengl

So I've been following a tutorial and when I tried to compile the below code:

```
#include <glut.h>
#include <iostream>

void render(void);
void keyboard(unsigned char c, int x, int y);
void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
    glutCreateWindow("Test GLUT App");

    glutDisplayFunc(render); // render
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);

    glutMainLoop(); // initialization finished. start rendering
}

void render(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3f(0.5, 0.2, 0.9);
    glVertex2f(-0.5, -0.5);
    glColor3f(0.1, 0.2, 0.5);
    glVertex2f(0.0, -0.5);
    glColor3f(0.3, 0.9, 0.7);
    glVertex2f(0.0, 0.5);
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();  
}

void keyboard(unsigned char c, int x, int y)
{
    if(c == 27)
    {
        exit(0);
    }
}

void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if(button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON)
    {
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

I get **3 errors** out of nowhere:

**Error 1 error C2381: 'exit' : redefinition; __declspec(noreturn) differs  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\stdlib.h 353**

**Error 2 error C3861: 'exit': identifier not found  ....main.cpp   45**

**Error 3 error C3861: 'exit': identifier not found  ....main.cpp   53**

Does anyone see why this error appears? Im using VS2010.

Comment: possible duplicate of [GLUT exit redefinition error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402/glut-exit-redefinition-error)

Comment: Try including glut.h after you include iostream.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to `#include <cstdlib>`.

edit:

You are probably following a very known tutorial that provides a header file for you.

This will help you then [GLUT exit redefinition error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402/glut-exit-redefinition-error)

Comment: If GLUT is declarting `exit` in the global namespace, it's a bad sign with regards to the quality of the library.

Comment: @JamesKanze Bad or not it is (i think) the only one available out there that makes entry easy for beginners.

Comment: @RedX I don't see where it helps anyone.  If the library needs `std::exit`, it should include `<cstdlib>`.  Defining `exit` in global namespace results in undefined behavior, and is _never_ correct.

Comment: @JamesKanze the library itself is not C++ only C because opengl is only C. So there is no options to define namespaces. But IMHO you are right. I have no idea why it defines an `exit` function.

Answer (score 2):

If your Visual Studio throws a build error saying IntelliSense did not identify 'exit' then you must include **process.h**

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `using namespace std` to the top. I'm not sure if this will fix it but i had a similar error earlier and that fixed it. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

u need to declare header simple as work , works in my comp

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <glut.h>
#include <iostream>
```