# what does this error say?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

when I run my open gl project, I face with this error :

```
error C2381: 'exit' : redefinition; __declspec(noreturn) differs
```

I used visual studio 2010 before, and don't have any problem. but since I use visual studio 2012, I face this error.
How can I solve it?

Comment: Here is something that could help: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4cf463c1-5fee-4daa-b135-be8b06ab7f8f/error-c2381-exit-redefinition-declspecnoreturn-differs?forum=Vsexpressvc

Comment: You should search for error first, Both Bing and Google's first result gave the link mentioned by @MonkeyZeus.

Comment: possible duplicate of [GLUT exit redefinition error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402/glut-exit-redefinition-error)

Comment: @Ajay I have come to terms that StackOverflow must translate to `www.googleitforme.com` in several, if not all, languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402/glut-exit-redefinition-error)

> or this... To fix the error, right click on the project name in the Solution Explorer tab and select Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor definitions and append GLUT_BUILDING_LIB to the existing definitions, seperated by semicolons.

As per @Alex the solution worked before because some these switches are correctly defined.