# Sierpinski gasket

Tags: c++, opengl

i was writing a code in C/C++ and i face an error .

```
#include "glut.h"
#include <random>

// Classes and structs // 
struct GLPoint {
    GLfloat x, y;
};

// Method(s) Declration // 
void drawDot(GLfloat, GLfloat);
void serpinski_render(void);
void myInti(void); 

// Method(s) Implementation // 
void drawDot(GLfloat x, GLfloat y){
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex2i(x, y);
    glEnd();
}
void serpinski_render(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);  // Clear the screen from anything is displayed on it 
    GLPoint T[3] = { { 10, 10 }, { 600, 10 }, { 300, 600 } }; // the three points of parent triangle 

    int index = rand() % 3;  // this mean i will choose a random number between 0 , 3 
    GLPoint point = T[index];
    drawDot(point.x, point.y);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 5500; i++) // a loop that going to run 5500 ( a very big number ) 
    {
        index = rand() % 3;
        point.x = (point.x + T[index].x) / 2;
        point.y = (point.y + T[index].y) / 2;

        drawDot(point.x, point.y); 
    }
    glFlush(); 

}
void myInti(void)
{
    glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 0);  // a white background 
    glColor3f(0, 0, 0); // black points 
    glPointSize(3); // 3 pixel point size 

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); 
    glLoadIdentity(); 
    gluOrtho2D(0, 640, 0, 480); 
}


// Main Method //
void main(int argc ,char ** argv )
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv); // intilize toolkit 
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 150); 
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB); 
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480); // windows size is 640 x 480 
    glutDisplayFunc(serpinski_render); 

    myInti(); 
    glutMainLoop(); 
}
```

i dont know if it will work fine but this code should produce me Sierpinski triangle .
and i face every time i use C++ library in this case the random lib this problem in the stdlib.h making me confused never face something like it before

*Error  1   error C2381: 'exit' : redefinition; __declspec(noreturn) differs    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\stdlib.h 376*

Comment: _note_
i already found some posts about this topics on stack overflow non-work for me .

like including the stdlib

Comment: Looks like there is a collision between library versions, glut and visual studio.  Try rebuilding glut using your version of Visual Studio.

Comment: Try changing `void main` to something more legal like `int main()` and append `return EXIT_SUCCESS;` to the end.

Comment: about rebuilding using visual studio i am searching nothing to found about it ..
and when i used int main and return EXIT_SUCCESS ;
the same error

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402/glut-exit-redefinition-error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an incompatibility between glut.h and Visual Studio .NET, which is the usage of both "glut.h" and  in your case.
You can solve it by just declaring:

```
#include <random>
#include "glut.h"
```

instead of:

```
#include "glut.h"
#include <random>
```

Please read [this description](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/research/graphics/resources/GLUT/GLUT.htm) for further information and for an another solution. ("Header (.h) files" section)

Also your code will possibly fail because of not creating window. You can use glutCreateWindow to create a window. You can also solve this issue by arranging your main like below:

```
void main(int argc ,char ** argv )
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv); // intilize toolkit 
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 150); 
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB); 
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480); // windows size is 640 x 480 
    glutCreateWindow("A title");
    myInti(); 
    glutDisplayFunc(serpinski_render); 

    glutMainLoop(); 
}
```

Please also read [this information](https://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node16.html) for glutCreateWindow function.

Comment: oh i don't believe its that simple i been looking all day thank sir .. u just made my day now

Answer (score 0):

You probably have this code in `glut.h`:

```
# ifndef GLUT_BUILDING_LIB
extern _CRTIMP void __cdecl exit(int);
# endif
```

The `glut.h` header is quite old. This was probably a workaround for an old VC deficiency.   Visual C now seems to have a declaration that conflicts with this one.  The easy solution is to just delete these lines from the header, since there is a valid definition in `stdlib.h`.

By the way, all the `glVertex`, `glBegin`, `glEnd`, matrix stack, and many other OpenGL calls are deprecated in favor of shaders.

Perhaps there is also a newer/better `glut` available.  I'd check that out.

Comment: I have recently switched to [freeGlut](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/) which I think could be considered as a newer/better `glut`.

Comment: i tried the easy way saddly didn't work i will check the glut out right now